# If $z=(1-a\cos\theta)+i(1-b\sin\theta)$ and it's locus is $x+y=1$, show that $a^2+b^2≤1$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, solution-verification

If $z=(1-a\cos\theta)+i(1-b\sin\theta)$ where $a,b,\theta$ are real and it's locus is $x+y=1$, I want to show that $a^2+b^2≤1$. However I think there is a problem with the question.

Letting $x=(1-a\cos\theta)$ and $y=(1-b\sin\theta)$ I get the equation $a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta=1$

However if I use auxiliary angle I get: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin{\left(\theta+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\right)}=1$. In this case since $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}≥0$ we can deduce that $0≤\sin{\left(\theta+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\right)}≤1$, which means that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}≥1$. So instead of $a^2+b^2≤1$ the result $a^2+b^2≥1$ is derived instead. So have I made a mistake in this proof or is the question's premise incorrect?

Comment: You can try for yourself with $\,\theta = \pi/3\,$ for example.

Comment: @dxiv, With that I got $4-2\sqrt{3}b+b^2≤1$, which is false cos the minimum is 3.25, so the question is wrong right?

Comment: Right, the correct condition is $\,\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \ge 1\,$.